# Do I need OAuth2.0 for Google App Engine PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Since I can't get an OAuth2.0 token working on my Google Site, and since Google Sites will not host PHP, I'm considering implementing GAE for PHP.  I know that my app.yaml file has the *option* for authentication, but I'm wondering if I will generally be able to send a request to GAE (via Javascript's XMLHttpRequest method) if I don't have have a OAuth2.0 access token.

Thanks in advance for the newbie help.  The question is as simple as it seems; I just don't want to spend three days developing if I have to fix my authentication problems anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the GAE PHP auth option in app.yaml doesn't require your app to handle OAuth2.0 access tokens.

This authentication option uses the simple [Users PHP API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/). An app using it can authenticate users with **either** Google Accounts **or** accounts on a Google Apps domain (configurable in the app's settings on the Developer Console).

The usage in your app would be [fairly simple](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/#PHP_User_authentication_in_PHP), based only on creating some URLs. All the heavy stuff happens between the browser and the Google infrastructure, transparently for your app.